# help, I think I accidentally uninstalled my graphics drivers while installing Ubuntu, now I am unable to switch back 1920*1080p

Tags: 20.04, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I decided to switch from windows to Ubuntu and installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

After the installation was complete my display switched to 1028 * 720 p and it looks really irritating to work with it.

I tried xrandr and tried getting the option of 1920 * 1080 p but after clicking that option my screen goes black and I have to restart my PC from the power switch

Any kind of help would really be appreciated

Comment: Graphics drivers are installed in the OS so, if you've replaced Windows with Ubuntu, you will need to install drivers again. Could you [edit] your question to include some information, such as the brand and model of video card you're using? Have you tried to install any video drivers already?

Comment: @matigo no i dont have a video card im using integrated graphics from my cpu

Comment: Search for "additional drivers" from the cog wheel top left and pick a device driver if there are any shown. If there are none your probably do not have a device problem but it is something else. And please provide the command you issued that you believe removed your graphics driver. If there is reversing the command will be a possible answer to the problem

Comment: @Rinzwind oh right it's not a device problem, i mean i used xrandr to get an option of 1920 1080p but then when i click it the screen goes black